# Why is Jonah 1:17 missing in the BHS?

Tags: jonah, versification

I was checking the BHS and saw that Verse 17 of Jonah is missing. I can't find the reason why it is omitted. Can anyone tell me why Jonah 1:17 is ommited in the BHS?
[image]

Answer (score 5):

**Why is Jonah 1:17 missing in the BHS (Biblia Hebraica Stuttgartensia)?**

- The verse is not missing. - Unlike English bibles (KJV, RSV, ESV, NASB, etc.), the Masoretic Text (MT) of the Tanakh never had verse Jonah 1:17. **Jonah 1:17 [is] verse Yonah 2:1.**

**Yonah / Jonah 2:1** [MT]

> “And YHVH appointed a great fish to swallow up Yonah, and-Yonah was in the belly of the-fish for three days and three nights.” ( וַיְמַ֚ן יְהֹוָה֙ דָּ֣ג גָּד֔וֹל לִבְלֹ֖עַ אֶת־יוֹנָ֑ה וַיְהִ֚י יוֹנָה֙ בִּמְעֵ֣י הַדָּ֔ג שְׁלֹשָׁ֥ה יָמִ֖ים וּשְׁלֹשָׁ֥ה לֵילֽוֹת )

**Jonah 1:17** [KJV]

> Now the Lord had prepared a great fish to swallow up Jonah. And Jonah was in the belly of the fish three days and three nights.

Comment: Does this mean all of chapter 2 is misaligned or does it run together again by doubling up shortly?

Comment: In English bibles, all verses in Jonah - chapter 2 remain misaligned (from the Tanakh) ending at verse 10 instead of verse 11.